# Jsdoc casting htmlElements to other types without typescript

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I've been trying to use `jsdoc` with `ts-check` for error check/autocomplete/intellisense, the only issue i've been having are selections (which i cannot cast as i do not use typescript).

when i try to set the type of an element it will instead underline it and display the following error

> Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'

```
// @ts-check

/**
 * @type {HTMLInputElement}
 */
const { list } = document.getElementById(someInput)
```

if i remove `ts-check` it will remove the error and offer `intellisense` but it will not show errors anymore.

I have been looking for solutions to this issue but they are all for typescript .

Comment: `document.getElementById(someInput)` returns `HTMLElement | null`, you may not always be able to de-structure it to get `list`. If you're using VSCode, it might be worth using [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) in combination with [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) installed. If you want typescript checking, why not use typescript?

Comment: @Harrison jsdoc + typescript solve most of the problems and remove compilation step which may significantly slowdown development. Also, I like the idea of types in comments because it doesn't allow you to use syntax different from JavaScript (like enums) and clearly separate types from runtime code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/**@type {}*/(expression)` is an equivalent of type cast `as` operator from TypeScript

```
const { list } = /**@type {HTMLInputElement}*/(document.getElementById(someInput));
```